# Complex Gradients

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient

I'm trying to figure out how to have a complex gradient, like this image, in Flutter, but I can't figure it out.

[image]

I have tried doing a stack of colored box decorations with different gradients, but they don't come out looking very good or clean.
Anyone have any suggestions or packages that can make complex gradients?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  gradient: LinearGradient(
    begin: Alignment.topRight,
    end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    stops: [
      0.1,
      0.4,
      0.6,
      0.9
    ],
  colors: [
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.red,
    Colors.indigo,
    Colors.teal
  ])),
```

But this might not be the complex gradient you want.

You could also just create a photo and use that for the background.